# Abrikosov and his fluxoids (why only one ?)

Tags: superconductivity

In superconductivity, when we solve the ginzburg-landau equations relative to a 2 dimensional plane immersed in a magnetic field, we find that a periodic lattice of vortices is a solution. When we look at the higher critical magnetic field, we suppose that the plane is covered with vortices each having inside a flux equal to an integer n times the quantum flux $h/e$ and we assume just $n=1$. I can understand intuitively why this is the less energical configuration (it's just easier to make some holes somewhere else), but does someone know how to show it explicitly (actually, I didn't know how to calculate the free energy associate without having the complete solution which is an Infinite serie...) or know some reference that proves why should this state with multi-fluxoids be unstable ?

Thanks a lot if you can help !

Comment: You can carry out explicit computations in the Landau-Ginzburge model. For example see Exercise 6.6.2 here: http://people.ccmr.cornell.edu/~clh/BT-GL/6.6.pdf

Comment: The exercice in question already assumed what I was wondering. But, the lecture itself gives an answer in the preceding sections. Thank you !